# Read a python variable in a shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell

my python file has these 2 variables:

```
week_date = "01/03/16-01/09/16"
cust_id = "12345"
```

how can i read this into a shell script that takes in these 2 variables?

my current shell script requires manual editing of "dt" and "id". I want to read the python variables into the shell script so i can just edit my python parameter file and not so many files.

shell file:

```
#!/bin/sh

dt="01/03/16-01/09/16" 
cust_id="12345"
```

In a new python file i could just import the parameter python file.

Comment: They're set where? At module level?

Comment: it is at module level

Comment: BTW, using the `#!/bin/sh` shebang or invoking it with `sh scriptname` makes your script a POSIX sh script, not a bash script. Since your question is tagged bash, I'm assuming that that was a mistake and that you meant to use bash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider something akin to the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ NOT /bin/sh, which doesn't have process substitution available.

python_script='
import sys
d = {}                                 # create a dict to store values in
exec(open(sys.argv[1], "r").read(), d) # exec code with that dict as namespace
for k in sys.argv[2:]:
  print("%s\0" % str(d[k]).split("\0")[0]) # extract values
'

read_python_vars() {
  local python_file=$1; shift
  local varname
  for varname; do
    IFS= read -r -d '' "${varname#*:}"
  done < <(python -c "$python_script" "$python_file" "${@%%:*}")
}
```

You might then use this as:

```
read_python_vars config.py week_date:dt cust_id:id
echo "Customer id is $id; date range is $dt"
```

...or, if you didn't want to rename the variables as they were read, simply:

```
read_python_vars config.py week_date cust_id
echo "Customer id is $cust_id; date range is $week_date"
```

---

Advantages:

- Unlike a naive regex-based solution (which would have trouble with some of the details of Python parsing -- try teaching `sed` to handle both raw and regular strings, and both single and triple quotes without making it into a hairball!) or a similar approach that used newline-delimited output from the Python subprocess, this will correctly handle any object for which `str()` gives a representation with no NUL characters that your shell script can use.
- Running content through the Python interpreter also means you can determine values programmatically -- for instance, you could have some Python code that asks your version control system for the last-change-date of relevant content.

  Think about scenarios such as this one:

  ```py
  start_date = '01/03/16'
  end_date = '01/09/16'
  week_date = '%s-%s' % (start_date, end_date)
  ```

  ...using a Python interpreter to parse Python means you aren't restricting how people can update/modify your Python config file in the future.

Now, let's talk caveats:

- If your Python code has side effects, those side effects will obviously take effect (just as they would if you chose to `import` the file as a module in Python). Don't use this to extract configuration from a file whose contents you don't trust.
- Python strings are Pascal-style: They can contain literal NULs. Strings in shell languages are C-style: They're terminated by the first NUL character. Thus, some variables can exist in Python than cannot be represented in shell without nonliteral escaping. To prevent an object whose `str()` representation contains NULs from spilling forward into other assignments, this code terminates strings at their first NUL.

---

Now, let's talk about implementation details.

- `${@%%:*}` is an expansion of `$@` which trims all content after and including the first `:` in each argument, thus passing only the Python variable names to the interpreter. Similarly, `${varname#*:}` is an expansion which trims everything up to and including the first `:` from the variable name passed to `read`. See [the bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).
- Using `<(python ...)` is process substitution syntax: The `<(...)` expression evaluates to a filename which, when read, will provide output of that command. Using `< <(...)` redirects output from that file, and thus that command (the first `<` is a redirection, whereas the second is part of the `<(` token that starts a process substitution). Using this form to get output into a `while read` loop avoids the bug mentioned in [BashFAQ #24 ("I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- The `IFS= read -r -d ''` construct has a series of components, each of which makes the behavior of `read` more true to the original content:

  - Clearing `IFS` for the duration of the command prevents whitespace from being trimmed from the end of the variable's content.
  - Using `-r` prevents literal backslashes from being consumed by `read` itself rather than represented in the output.
  - Using `-d ''` sets the first character of the empty string `''` to be the record delimiter. Since C strings are NUL-terminated and the shell uses C strings, that character is a NUL. This ensures that variables' content can contain any non-NUL value, including literal newlines.

  See [BashFAQ #001 ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more on the process of reading record-oriented data from a string in bash.

Comment: if i keep variable name "dt" in the shell script, will it just be `dt=$week_date` after the code above?

Comment: should there be a space after the second `<` to be `< < (python -c "$python_script" filename.py week_date id)`

Comment: @jxn, see edits; I've made variable renaming in the process explicit, and tried to address your questions about `<()` syntax.

Comment: @jxn, ...btw, if you're getting an error about that syntax, it *probably* means your code is running with `/bin/sh` rather than with `bash`.

Comment: I am facing this error `KeyError: 'week_date'` when I try to reproduce the solution @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @shrikanthsingh, that means you don't really have the Python variable set (at least, not in the relevant scope). I'd suggest asking a separate question so you can attach a [MRE].

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you for the nudge to update this for Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers give a way to do exactly what you ask for, but I think the idea is a bit crazy. There's a simpler way to satisfy both scripts - move those variables into a config file. You can even preserve the simple assignment format.

Create the config itself: (ini-style)

```
dt="01/03/16-01/09/16"
cust_id="12345"
```

In python:

```
config_vars = {}
with open('the/file/path', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '=' in line:
            k,v = line.split('=', 1)
            config_vars[k] = v
week_date = config_vars['dt']
cust_id = config_vars['cust_id']
```

In bash:

```
source "the/file/path"
```

And you don't need to do crazy source parsing anymore. Alternatively you can just use json for the config file and then use `json` module in python and `jq` in shell for parsing.

Comment: The only thing I might change about this -- if you're going to have Python code parsing something written in shell, consider using `shlex` to actually get shell-compatible (well, POSIX-sh-compatible; it doesn't support bash extensions such as `$''`) lexing; that way you get support for multi-line assignments and the like.

Comment: So I was thinking of config being ini-style, not bash style (otherwise we're back at the crazy "parse other language" problem). If you need escaping, multiline or anything else, just go with json instead...

Comment: Something like: `import shlex; config_vars = dict([item.split('=', 1) for item in shlex.split(open('the/file/path').read()) if '=' in item])`; that way you get the escaping, multiline, &c. support and don't have to write the parser yourself. :)

Comment: ...otherwise you get bugs where `source "file"` -- by virtue of running through a real shell parser that interpolates expansions inside double quotes, treats `foo=bar baz` as an invocation of the command `baz` with the environment variable `foo` transiently set, etc -- doesn't do the exact same thing as your Python code does. Well, you have those bugs regardless, but _more of them_ without `shlex`.

Comment: ...which is to say: If you really want to parse an INI-style file correctly in bash, even one with no comments or section headers, it's more complex than just calling `source input.ini`. Not necessarily *much* more -- could look like this: `while IFS="=" read -r var value; do printf -v "$var" '%s' "$value"; done <input.ini`, and if the shell were modern bash (`printf -v` isn't available in baseline POSIX sh), that would suffice.

Comment: Anyhow -- I like the general idea; you have my upvote (and have had it since prior to my first comment); but there's still room for improvement if one wants to be pedantic about correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. You may want to modify it little bit for minor changes to include/exclude quotes as I didn't really tested it for your scenario:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec <$python_filename
while read line
do
        match=`echo $line|grep "week_date ="`
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                dt=`echo $line|cut -d '"' -f 2`
        fi

        match=`echo $line|grep "cust_id ="`
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                cust_id=`echo $line|cut -d '"' -f 2`
        fi
done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes. Look at what `echo $line` does if `line='hello * world'`.

Comment: ...and, of course, you've got all the usual problems that come with the naive string-parsing approach. What if it's `week_date = 'foo'` instead of `week_date = "foo"`? Or `week_date = r'foo'`? Or `week_date = get_current_datespan()`?

Comment: Also, there's no point to checking `$?` separately; just put your `grep` inside your `if` statement: `if printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep -q 'week_date ='; then`

Comment: ...using `printf '%s\n'` there because it's more reliable than `echo`; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html -- you'll see that `echo`'s output if the input string contains any backslash characters at all is undefined by the standard; it's allowed to interpolate backslash-escape sequences without any `-e` or `-E`; it's allowed to behave in an undefined way if `-n` is passed (note, *undefined* -- suppressing a trailing newline is *not* standards-defined behavior); and it's otherwise error-prone in general.

Comment: also, running a separate `grep` command for every line in your input file is *wildly* inefficient. Even if you wanted to stick to POSIX syntax, I'd suggest a `case` statement to do a pattern match instead. That is: `case $line in "week_date ="*) ... ;; "cust_id ="*) ... ;; esac`.

Comment: ...similarly, it's much more efficient to use parameter expansion or `read` to extract the values than to invoke an external pipeline. `dt=${line#*'"'}; dt=${dt%%'"'*}` has the same bugs as your `cut` does, but at least it's much, much faster.

Comment: I'd also suggest scoping the redirection to the `while read` loop -- otherwise, you've discarded your original stdin (even if you use `exec </dev/tty` later, you've lost information in terms of whether the script was run with stdin from somewhere else).

Comment: (And consider using the `-r` argument to `read`; look at how your script handles `cust_id = r"raw\string\with\backslash\literals"` without it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, here I suggested a working solution. I asked that person to verify to test it for his scenario as I didn't know the rest of the contents of python script. I appreciate your inputs/comments but I believe in getting the work done rather than making the script perfect and full-proof of all scenarios, most of the times its not needed!

Comment: If you test only for the situations you expect to occur, and assume something's good enough because your tests pass, then you're missing all the places bugs come in. At one former employer we lost TB of billing data backups because someone didn't quote correctly in their shell script (because filenames "couldn't ever" have anything that wasn't hex digits)... and they couldn't, until a buffer overflow dumped garbage including a whitespace-surrounded wildcard into a name and the script tried to delete that file.

Comment: Sometimes quick and sloppy is good enough, but if you're writing an answer somewhere it'll potentially be used by hundreds of people (because the *whole point* of StackOverflow is to build a canonical, reusable knowledge base), you need to worry about not just the OP but everyone else coming in with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `awk`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

WEEKDATE=$(awk -F \" '/^week_date =/ {print $2 }' config.py)
echo "$WEEKDATE"
```

Or with `grep` and `cut`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

WEEKDATE=$(grep '^week_date =' config.py | cut -d \" -f 2 -)
echo "$WEEKDATE"
```

These variants use the python file `config.py` and only work for single line strings.

Most likely you use some convention about what is a string.
Python strings have 4 possible delimiters: `"`, `'`, `"""` and `'''`.
Adjust the delimiter for the used string.