# Use variable from python file in a Bash Script

Tags: python, bash, variables

I am trying to create a Bash script to download a new file (a Bash script) with various variables and then update **OR** read one of those variables with one already stored in an existing Python file.

I cannot update the Python file, only read from it.

My Python file (config.py) just contains a list of variables, the one i'm interested in:

```py
iface  = 'wlan1'
```

My Bash script has a variable called `IWFace` which needs to be the same as `iface` from the Python file.

```
#!/bin/bash
IWFACE=wlan1
```

I have tried all sorts of ways to do this but it seems as I am reading from a Python file it turns out to be really quite difficult.

I have also tried a `sed read` command to read the variable from the Python file and use it to create a new variable in my Bash script but I'm struggling to make that work.

Is it actually possible? My only other idea was to ask the question via `read -p` and then store the answer as the variable but as it already exists I wanted to automate the process.

Comment: why not call/execute the bash script from python and pass the variable content as argument

Comment: As mentioned, i can not update the Python file

Comment: `$iface` is not a valid Python variable name. Without seeing either script, we really cannot offer much by way of guidance. Anyway, this seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). One approach is to write a new Python script which `import`s the nasty one and extracts the value of the variable and prints it so that you can retrieve it from your Bash script.

Comment: We need an _example_ of a Python script -- not necessarily your original, but something close enough that if we show you how to extract a variable from that script without changing it, you would accept that as an answer to your overall question -- included _in the body of your question itself_.

Comment: OK, so the python file is just a list of variables used in other python files, we refer to it as config.py. The variable is iface = wlan0 (apologies typo when i mentioned $iface).
My Bash file starts with
*****************
#!/bin/bash
IWFACE=wlan0
*****************
IWFace is then referenced in various other commands throughout the file

So i want to set IWFACE to be the same as what ever iface is set to in the python file

Comment: if you need to get text from file then maybe you should use `grep` and use `regex` in `grep`

Comment: maybe `IWFACE=\`grep -oP '(?<=iface = ).*' config.py\``

Comment: to skip `" "` from value `IWFACE=\`grep -oP '(?<=iface = ")[^"]*' config.py\``

Comment: for something more about `grep` or `sed` you may ask on similar portal [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Pigsfoot, [edit] the details needed for an answer **into the question**; content only present in comments doesn't count as included (and can be deleted at any time). And make sure you get the details right (`iface = wlan0` isn't valid Python code unless there's a previously-defined `wlan0` variable).

Comment: Based on the comments from @furas i have tried 'IWFace=`grep -oP '(?<=iface  = ).*' config.py`'. However the result is " 'wlan1' ". This is close but the '' needs removing but as they are special characters that form part of the code i can't seem to remove them

Comment: Right, what furas gave was correct when you said your script contained exactly `iface = wlan1` without any quotes (that's part of why it's important when showing examples to get the details _exactly_ right). You can find answers that work _with_ the quotes being present in the linked duplicate. (The one I wrote there will work even if the Python script runs some code to dynamically assign `iface`, though you might get undesired execution if it has module-scoped code without a `__name__ == '__main__'` guard protecting it).

Comment: 6 hours ago I added another comment with `IWFACE=\`grep -oP '(?<=iface = ")[^"]*' config.py\`` which should remove `" "` but if you use `' '` instead of `" "` then you should replace `"` with `'` (or maybe with `\'`) - or it should use `'` in place of `"` and`"` in place of `'` - example `IWFACE=\`grep -oP "(?<=iface = ')[^']*" config.py\``

Answer (score 2):

Write a python script that imports `config.py` and just prints the value of the variable `iface`. In your shell script call `IWFACE=$(python ...)`, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IWFACE=$(PYTHONPATH=. python -c 'from config import iface; print(iface)')
echo "$IWFACE"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
wlan1
```

`PYTHONPATH` just needs to be set to the directory where `config.py` exists.

The above is just for the OPs case where `My Python file (config.py) just contains a list of variables` and they're writing the script to print the value of a specific variable whose name they also hard-code. See @CharlesDuffy's comments below for risks of other usage.

Tested with python 3.9.16.

Comment: If that's an adequate answer, the duplicate proposed in comments on the question covers it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when I tried that I got a syntax error `$   File "<string>", line 6
    print "%s\0" % str(d[k]).split("\0")[0] # ...and extract your strings NUL-delimited
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
` so I was planning to fill this in with a complete script if/when I had it working. Maybe that's a python2 vs python3 thing, idk, I'm using `Python 3.9.16`.

Comment: I'm particularly interested in the solution as I'm using python quite a bit these days and I didn't expect this to be so relatively complicated.

Comment: Hmm, lessee if I can reproduce that.

Comment: ...you're right, it's a Python 2-vs-3 thing. Fix upcoming on the other post.

Comment: (s/upcoming/completed/)

Comment: No errors now but no output when running it as `read_python_vars 'config.py' iface` - now I'll have to actually read the question and answer I suppose .... :-)

Comment: Turned out I just had to actually read the code a bit better to add a `echo "$iface"`. That's working, thanks.

Comment: I feel like there's GOT to be a simpler way though.... I'll think more about that and maybe post an answer over there if this gets closed as a dup.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I posted something simpler here for this specific question, feedback welcome. Thanks for the idea of providing the python script as a string rather than a file.

Comment: It _works_, certainly, just a bit more fragile. Assumes that changing PYTHONPATH won't break config.py, f/e; if it's using any libraries, that might not be sound. Strings with trailing newlines will also see them trimmed, vs having non-NUL content represented byte-for-byte.

Comment: The other thing is that the other approach trusts the Python file, but _doesn't_ trust the requested variable name. If someone can replace `iface` with `__import__('os').system('...')` in the position of the variable to be extracted at invocation time, you have an injection vulnerability.

Comment: Right, it's just for the OPs case where `My Python file (config.py) just contains a list of variables` and they're writing the script to print the value of a specific variable from it. I updated the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use `awk`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFACE=$(awk -F \' '/^iface =/ {print $2 }' config.py)
echo "$IFACE"
```

Or with `grep` and `cut`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFACE=$(grep '^iface =' config.py | cut -d \' -f 2 -)
echo "$IFACE"
```

Comment: Note that this won't work with all Python syntax. Strings don't need to use `'` -- they can use `"`, they can use triple-quotes, they can span multiple lines...

Comment: (And think about posting this on the preexisting, more-canonical copy of the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751930/read-a-python-variable-in-a-shell-script rather than here).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` to get text from file.

- option `-o` shows only matching part (not full line).
- option `-P` allows to use `Perl regex` and you can use `(?<= ...)` (for `positive lookbehind`) to find element which shouldn't be displayed in result.

If you have value in `" "` then

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IWFACE=$(grep -oP '(?<=iface = ")[^"]*' config.py)
echo $IWFACE
```

If you have value in `' '` then replace `'` with `"` and `'` with `"`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IWFACE=$(grep -oP "(?<=iface = ')[^']*" config.py)
echo $IWFACE
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found shorter version with `\K` instead of `(?<= ...)`

```
IWFACE=$(grep -oP 'iface = "\K[^"]*' config.py)
```

```
IWFACE=$(grep -oP "iface = '\K[^']*" config.py)
```

[Perl doc for (?<= ...) and \K](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?pattern))